# PUT and POSTS AS Cron commands PHP Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5, cron

I have put all my API calls methods in a model class. They are basic commands like create() read() search() store() etc.

For a start I made these in a controller class and now I'm trying to move the logic from the controller into a commands so I can run the scripts as a daily cronjob. For some reason they wont work as commands. Is this because you cant use PUT POST calls as cronjobs? Since it seams like the read functions works just fine but the PUTS and POSTS won't work.

And if it is so that I cant use PUT and POST in crons, is there a workaround for this?

Here is some example code

```
public function handle()
{
    $myModel = new MyModel;
    $thing = array(
        "title" => "My title",
        "user_id" => 12345,
        "org_id" => 54321,
    );

    $returned_id = $myModel->create($thing);
}


public function create($thing)
{
    $api_token = "XXXX";
    $url = "https://api.api-site.com/thing?api_token=" . $api_token;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $thing);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //array from the data that is sent back from the API
    $result = json_decode($output, 1);
    // check if an id came back
    if (!empty($result['data']['id'])) {
    $deal_id = $result['data']['id'];
    return $deal_id;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GET PUT POST DELETE HEAD are all http calls, these methods are determined by you framework routing by reading the HTTP headers and the calls are then redirected to appropriate function by the same routing. When you run a cronjob you are using CLI not HTTP so there are no headers and by default everything is interpreted as GET. REST methods are not ment and neither should be used anywhere else except http API calls. Now depending on you app loginc there are few things you can do:

1. Create a propper controller for CLI that manages which methods to access (better way).
2. Create a script that uses CURL to access your app via HTTP(s) with required HTTP method. (hacky way)
3. Rework your app so that REST API functionality does not need to be triggered from cron as they should not be tied in any way. (correct way)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have one question though. If what your saying is correct, my GET request should not work right? But in my crons this works just fine. The only thing that do not work is my PUT and POST requests.

Comment: Your GET will work, as GET is the default HTTP request method,  when you make a CLI request (via cron) your router will not have any http headers and jump to default, that is your GET.